# I found Calling Semaphoreslim.Wait and Semaphoreslim.WaitAsync at the same time cause a deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Why? Did I misunderstand something?

Run the following code, you will find that the final result is never output, which seems to cause a deadlock.

update: Please run TestSemaphoreSlimForMixUse()
a few more times, as I find it occasionally works fine.

**Define a method to call SemaphoreSlim.Wait:**

```
static void TestMethod(SemaphoreSlim sp, Action worker)
{
    sp.Wait();
    try
    {
        worker();
    }
    finally
    {
        sp.Release();
    }
}
```

**Define a method to call SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync:**

```
static async Task TestMethodAsync(SemaphoreSlim sp, Func<Task> worker)
{
    await sp.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    try
    {
        await worker();
    }
    finally
    {
        sp.Release();
    }
}
```

**Method used for testing:
Testing found that if you use one alone, you don't have a problem, and if you use both (mixed), you do.**

```
public static async Task TestSemaphoreSlimForMixUse()
{
    var taskList = new List<Task>();
    var countList = new List<int>();
    SemaphoreSlim sp = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var t = Task.Run(async () =>
        {

         //Note: The following two lines of code, if enabled together, cause the problem described. If only one of them is enabled, there is no problem.  
 

            //await TestMethodAsync(sp, async () => { countList.Add(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId); await Task.FromResult(0); }); 
            //TestMethod(sp, () => { countList.Add(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId); });

        });
        taskList.Add(t);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    Console.WriteLine($"Count：{countList.Count}");
}
```

Comment: Hm - cant spot any obvious mistakes or soemthing.

Comment: @sommmen Just now I added the test method instructions, you can run directly to see, there must be a problem.

Comment: In Method used for testing: 
Note: The following two lines of code, if enabled together, cause the problem described.  
If only one of them is enabled, there is no problem.

Comment: These seem to be just race conditions - if you lower the count to say 10 you'll see an output of 20 - so in the end all tasks are ran - but not in order

Comment: @sommmen Maybe not: when you change the number of times to 100, if you enable just one of them, the results will be printed instantly, but if you enable both of them, it will take a long time to print.

Comment: The obvious question here is, why isn't it immediately printed when both are enabled?  Is there anything to know about this?

Comment: I think this has something to do with new threads that keep to be spinned up because the sync methods will queue up waiting for their respective async tasks to be finished first. If you switch them around it'll run faster due to the sync tasks being able to release their threads.

Comment: @404 it does indeed generate a whole lot of threads.

Comment: @404 Can you elaborate on that?   When both are enabled, why does this result in continuous thread requisition?   When there's only one, it doesn't.

Comment: Because sometimes in our development, we might use it that way, and it would be dangerous.

Comment: @sommmen Yes, it's a problem phenomenon.

Comment: It doesn't deadlock, it eventually completes but it takes a few minutes.

Comment: @CHB_LT The Task.Run will create a new thread which will be released once your sync method is done. But because your sync method will have to wait on your async method to complete the thread can't be released untill that also completes. However because of your loop and the use of the semaphore it doesn't only wait for that one async method, but nearly all of them. So you end up having ~1000 threads waiting for the async methods to finish. Having that many threads open causes the degraded performance.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, not deadlocks, but thread consumption.

Comment: @404  Thanks. I understand part of that. But for synchronous methods waiting for asynchronous methods, The previous method 'await TestMethodAsync()', here 'TestMethodAsync()' will be pushed back here at 'await', and then, 'TestMethod())'-this sync method will be executed. I mean, the synchronous method here is not affected by the asynchronous method above, isn't it?

Comment: @CHB_LT I shouldn't have used the word sync *method* for it as it encapsulates more. The scope of the synchronous context isn't just the `TestMethod()`, but everything inside the function called in `Task.Run`.

Comment: In complex business scenarios, it may be unavoidable to use both, but how to solve this problem .. If you use just one of these(sync or async) you can do it almost instantaneously,  while two together (of course, some other code that may be executed in between) take several times longer (due to the constant opening of threads)?---Even if it ends up being twice or three times longer, it's at least understandable and acceptable(But it turns out to be many times longer than that.).

Comment: @404 What do you think of this situation?  Or are there any references?

Comment: @CHB_LT Hard to say since I don't know the process. But if you need something that's as close to this code as possible but without the issues I would consider replacing the `for` loop and `Task.Run` with `Parallel.ForEach|Async`. It manages the number of threads for you.

Comment: @404 Thank you very much for your advice.  Maybe I need to conduct better research.

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that when the number of tasks is higher than the maximum number of threads using for running task parallelly, it can cause deadlock in this case.

For example, if you have 1000 tasks but only 4 threads to run all tasks. It is possible that all 4 threads are waiting at `TestMethod` for the lock to be released, while the lock is already released for `TestMethodAsync` in some other task but there is no thread available to continue that task because they are all waiting for the lock, hence deadlock.

Comment: Yes, your example is correct, but in the test in question, there is no limit on the maximum number of threads, and the maximum number of threads is by default greater than the number of loops defined here -1000

Comment: It is up to the underlying TaskScheduler and ultimately, with default scheduler, the ThreadPool to decide how many threads should be used. It only guarantees that the number of threads will reach configured number of minimum threads, but it does not guarantee to use more than that. By default the minimum number of threads is the number of CPU cores available, which usually less than 1000.

Comment: Here is my test, which shows that it uses only single thread to run the whole 1000 tasks - shorturl.at/gyzJ7

Comment: Can't seem to open your sample.  However, I am absolutely certain of the current problem, and then how we can better solve this scenario, see here:  ..

Comment: In complex business scenarios, it may be unavoidable to use both, but how to solve this problem .. If you use just one of these(sync or async) you can do it almost instantaneously, while two together (of course, some other code that may be executed in between) take several times longer (due to the constant opening of threads)?---Even if it ends up being twice or three times longer, it's at least understandable and acceptable(But it turns out to be many times longer than that.).